# Variables across Azure Pipeline stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I saw the changes went in to allow us to consume variable outputs from previous stages. Has anyone got it working? Release info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages

I tried this:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  MyVar: 'MyVal'

stages:
- stage: Save_Variable

  jobs:
  - job: Save_Variable
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar;]NewVal"
        name: MyOutputVar

- stage: Read_Variables
  dependsOn: Save_Variable

  jobs:
    - job: Read_Variable
      variables:
        prevStageVar: $[stageDependencies.Save_Variable.Save_Variable.outputs['MyOutputVar.MyVar']]
      steps:
      - powershell: 'Write-Host "Get Stage variable: $(prevStageVar)"'
```

Mentioned here https://www.razorspoint.com/2020/05/05/azure-devops-sprint-update-cross-staging-variables-supported-natively/ But I wasn't able to get it working.

Any luck from others?

Answer (score 1):

All good, it just needs the `;isOutput=true`

https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/gvo3ml/variables_across_stages/